# csv is writing all rows in one column python

Tags: python, xml, csv

i am writing csv of my xml file which contain  Date , ID , title , Abstract when i am running my  code it is writing all rows in one column as list it not writing column separately it is writing like - ["123,2018,abs,ABC"] ["123,2018,abs,ABC"] in one column not separately

code :

```
import os 
import lxml.etree as ET 
from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

import csv

path = '/home/shayez/Desktop/project/kk'

listfile = []
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:

    listfile.append(name)


pmdata = []    

for name2 in listfile:


        full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('project/kk',name2))
        dom = ET.parse(full_file)
        pmdat = dom.findall('PubmedArticle')
        pmdata.append(pmdat)                         

def Print_Data ():

    with open ('/home/shayez/Desktop/karim.csv','wt') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = "\t")
        header = ['PMID','Date','Title','Abstract']
        writer.writerow(header)
        rows = []
        row = zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue = '')


        for d in pmdata:
            for c in d :
                PMID = c.find('MedlineCitation/PMID').text
                title = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle').text
                Date = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year')
                Date2 = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/MedlineDate')
                Abstract = c.find('MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText')


                if Abstract is None :
                     pass

                elif Date is None:
                    print PMID,"\t",Date2.text, "\t",title ,"\t",Abstract.text
                    rows.append([PMID,Date2.text,title,Abstract.text])

                else :

                    print PMID,"\t",Date.text, "\t",title ,"\t",Abstract.text
                    rows.append([PMID,Date.text,title,Abstract.text])

            writer.writerow(rows)

Print_Data()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are adding the newline character to the end of each row. You need to put `\n` at the end of each row. You can do that by just concatenating  `"\n"` on the end of the row string before writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what doglol99 has said, you can add an extra parameter to print as follows

```py
print "test", "test", end="\n"
```

This is just a more high-level approach to the problem.